# How can I make `fsck` actually check the healthiness of my disk, partitions, filesystems, and LVs?

Tags: filesystems, partition, lvm, ext4, fsck

I want to check the healthiness of my disk, partitions, filesystems, and LVs. So I run `fsck`. I heard  to use `fsck` on a filesystem, I need to boot into a live Lubuntu from a bootable flash drive and umount filesystem beforehand, so I did. But why `fsck` always return immediately? How can I make `fsck` actually check the healthiness of my disk, partitions, filesystems, and LVs? Thanks.

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

$ sudo umount /dev/sda
umount: /dev/sda: not mounted.

$ sudo fsck /dev/sda
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sda is in use.
e2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting.

$ sudo fsck /dev/sda1
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
fsck.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
/dev/sda1: 12 files, 1557/130812 clusters
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda2
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ echo $?
0



$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name                  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB  fat32        EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      538MB   500GB  500GB                                     lvm


Warning: The driver descriptor says the physical block size is 2048 bytes, but
Linux says it is 512 bytes.
Ignore/Cancel? I                                                          
Model: General UDisk (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 16.1GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 2048B/512B
Partition Table: mac
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name   Flags
 1      2048B   6143B   4096B                Apple
 2      6222kB  8614kB  2392kB               EFI


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-home: 444GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  444GB  444GB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-swap: 4295MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  4295MB  4295MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/lubuntu--vg-root: 51.5GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  51.5GB  51.5GB  ext4


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram3: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram1: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram2: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Unknown (unknown)
Disk /dev/zram0: 444MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start  End    Size   File system     Flags
 1      0.00B  444MB  444MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: fsck can only be used to check the filesystem consistency.

Answer (score 2):

From `man fsck.ext2`

> e2fsck is used to check the ext2/ext3/ext4 family of file systems. 
>   For   ext3 and ext4 filesystems that use a journal, if the  system 
>   has  been
>          shut  down  uncleanly without any errors, normally, after replaying the
>          committed transactions  in the  journal,  the  file  system  should  be
>          marked  as clean.   Hence, for filesystems that use journalling, e2fsck
>          will normally replay the journal and exit, unless its superblock  indi‐
>          cates that further checking is required.

From further down in the same man page:

> -f     Force checking even if the file system seems clean.

So... running `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1` will cause fsck to check the disk, even if the superblock is marked as clean.

Answer (score 1):

- `/dev/sda` (sdb, sdc...) are (hardware) devices -- the actual disk you can use as a brick!
- `/dev/sda1` (2,3...) are partitions of the above
- `fsck` can only work on the second
- you need something like [SMART](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/S.M.A.R.T.) for the first
- `gparted` shows how the second nests in the first

Admittedly Linux causes some confusion by calling both "device".

LVs are an extra abstraction on top of (physical) FSes (above).